# jquery image slider fadeIn not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am building an Image slider from this tutorial. [youtube.com](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z277ZUHNnnE&t=331s)

I cannot get the first image to fadeIn
I have reviewed the code several times but cannot see where i went wrong.
Here is my code

HTML

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Helping Develope | Jquery Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div id='slider'>
        <img id="1" src="Images/Image1.jpg">
        <img id="2" src="Images/Image2.jpg">
        <img id="3" src="Images/Image3.png">
        <img id="4" src="Images/Image4.png">
    </div>

    <a href="#" class='left'>Previous</a>
    <a href="#" class='right'>Next</a>

</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
    .wrapper{
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #slider {
        width:600px;
        height:400px;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:30px auto;
    }
    #slider > img{
        width: 600px;
        height:400px;
        float:left;
        display:none;
    }

    a {
        padding:5px 10px;
        background-color:#F0F0F0;
        margin-top:30;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: red;

    }

    a.left{
        float:left;
    }

    a.right{
        float:right;
    }
```

Javascript

```
var sliderInt=1;
var sliderNext=2;

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#slider > img#1").fadeIn(300);
startSlider()
});
function startSlider(){
    count = $("#slider > img").size();
    loop= setInterval(function(){
        if(sliderNext > count) {    
            sliderNext=1;
            sliderInt=1;
        }           
        $("#slider>img").fadeOut(300);
        $("#slider>img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);
        sliderInt = sliderNext;
        sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;
    }, 3000);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code you added `}};` insted of `});`

```js
var sliderInt=1;
var sliderNext=2;

$(document).ready(function(){
$("#slider > img#1").fadeIn(300);
startSlider()
});
function startSlider(){
  count = $("#slider > img").length;
  loop= setInterval(function(){
  if(sliderNext > count) {  
   sliderNext=1;
   sliderInt=1;
  }   
  $("#slider>img").fadeOut(300);
  $("#slider>img#" + sliderNext).fadeIn(300);
  sliderInt = sliderNext;
  sliderNext = sliderNext + 1;
 }, 3000);
}
```

```css
.wrapper{
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #slider {
        width:600px;
        height:400px;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:30px auto;
    }
    #slider > img{
        width: 600px;
        height:400px;
        float:left;
        display:none;
    }

    a {
        padding:5px 10px;
        background-color:#F0F0F0;
        margin-top:30;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: red;

    }

    a.left{
        float:left;
    }

    a.right{
        float:right;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Helping Develope | Jquery Slider</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/slider.css" type="text/css">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div id='slider'>
        <img id="1" src="http://placehold.it/600x400g/ff0000">
        <img id="2" src="http://placehold.it/600x400g/00ff00">
        <img id="3" src="http://placehold.it/600x400g/0000ff">
        <img id="4" src="http://placehold.it/600x400g/000000">
    </div>

    <a href="#" class='left'>Previous</a>
    <a href="#" class='right'>Next</a>

</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Check my answer and if you stuck somewhere just update the question

Comment: The loop is not working as it should. image1 comes up but it does not cycle to rest.

Comment: I think you diden't see my code i have implemented in my answer just run and see. In your code you forgot to reset in setInterval `if(sliderNext > count) {  
   sliderNext=1;
   sliderInt=1;
  }`

Comment: New code is in my question. I added the if statement you suggested. Still no change.

Comment: Its all good it can be the cache problem try to run your code in incognito window

Comment: I ran it in google chrome ingognito and still nothing

Comment: inspect element in chrome and see the console for any error

Comment: jquery.js:2 jQuery.Deferred exception: $(...).size is not a function TypeError: $(...).size is not a function
    at startSlider (file:///home/faradaysmage/Desktop/Slider/js/slider.js:9:30)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (file:///home/faradaysmage/Desktop/Slider/js/slider.js:6:1)
    at j (file:///home/faradaysmage/Desktop/Slider/js/jquery.js:2:29948)
    at k (file:///home/faradaysmage/Desktop/Slider/js/jquery.js:2:30262) undefinedr.Deferred.exceptionHook @ jquery.js:2
jquery.js:2 Uncaught TypeError: $(...).size is not a function(…)

Comment: Which version of jquery are you using. Are you using any other javascript

Comment: I am using version 3.1.1

Comment: Thats causing problem change with v2.1.1 take from here  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js and replace it with your previous file

Comment: Or you have to replace the `count = $("#slider > img").size();` with `count = $("#slider > img").length;`

Comment: Thank you so much! It worked. So .size used to determine the value of the integer?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the working snippet. Is it what are you searching for?

```js
var sliderInt=1,
    sliderNext=2;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#slider > img#1").fadeIn(300);
})
```

```css
    .wrapper {
        width: 600px;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    #slider {
        width:600px;
        height:400px;
        overflow:hidden;
        margin:30px auto;
    }
    #slider > img{
        width: 600px;
        height:400px;
        float:left;
        display:none;
    }

    a {
        padding:5px 10px;
        background-color:#F0F0F0;
        margin-top:30;
        text-decoration: none;
        color: red;

    }

    a.left{
        float:left;
    }

    a.right{
        float:right;
    }
```

```html
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Helping Develope | Jquery Slider</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>

<div class="wrapper">

    <div id='slider'>
        <img id="1" src="Images/Image1.jpg">
        <img id="2" src="Images/Image2.jpg">
        <img id="3" src="Images/Image3.png">
        <img id="4" src="Images/Image4.png">
    </div>

    <a href="#" class='left'>Previous</a>
    <a href="#" class='right'>Next</a>

</div>

<script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="js/slider.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I ran the code you posted and still am not getting the image to pop up

Comment: I figured out the problem